# Pending review count in the status bar

Tags: feature-request, review, notifications

In the status bar at the top of the site there is already notifications with counters regarding recent inbox messages, recent achievements, current reputation and current badges.

However, I was still wondering why the "Review" link remains static and why it does not indicate dynamically when there are some pending reviews? It would be more practical than having to manually check the queues and poll pending notifications (that's a good job... for a computer).

Actually, the question now becomes even "worse" since after having encountered [this message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211728/how-did-this-answer-manage-to-garner-50-incorrect-not-an-answer-flags-in-less/212716#212716) I have the impression that this feature actually existed in the past with a dedicated orange counter:

[image]

This feature was apparently added in 2013 but has apparently been removed. Did it had some unexpected negative side-effects?

**Edit**: I'm more and more confused... I have access to the "First posts" and "Late answers" review queues since a relatively long time and never saw this button. I have now access to the "Low quality posts" and "Suggested edit" and reviewed a few "low quality post" without still ever seeing this button... And now I just saw it popup very rapidly stating there was one "Suggested edit" pending... Now, again, there is 1 first post and 1 suggested edit pending and it popups again but only tells about "1 suggested edit pending approval".

I therefore guess this button still exists but is linked only to the suggested edit queue, and do not take the other ones into account?

Comment: I haven't noticed it being removed. I still have orange notifiers on mine.

Comment: Ok, so I guess this means that this is a privilege to be acquired with higher reputation (how much?), maybe to get highest profile user more involved in handling the review queue than lower profiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that orange icon displays the number of reviews waiting in the queues to which you have privileges - e.g. since you don't yet have close privileges you wont be seeing that queue.
On the other hand, you should be seeing the number of reviews in the suggested edits, and etc queues - which you probably do, since these are usually quite small and handled rather quickly.

So it is possible that you haven't seen it simply because you weren't on the site when the queues weren't empty, and then recently you were...

Comment: Possible, but in my case it seem to appear quite clearly that this counter only reflect the "Suggested edit" queue, and do not take into account the other ones. As soon as there some activity in this queue, this counter appear with the size of this queue (and only this one even when there are posts waiting in the others). Even now I saw 2 messages in the "Low quality posts" queues but still nothing... I begin to wonder if it is an expected behavior...

Comment: Yes, I meant to say that it does not include ALL the queues - close votes, reopen votes, suggested edits... I'm not actually sure which ones it does include, but it is clear that the lower priority queues are not.

Comment: Ok, I think this answers my question. This feature already exists, but instead of counting the number of all pending reviews without discrimination it focuses only on higher priority queues (like close and edit) needing more attention to be handled quicker. I've learned something, thanks :)

Comment: I've actually only ever see the suggested edits one.  I always have to click "review" to see the others.

Comment: Indicator is only for suggested edits for users < 10k

Answer (score 2):

The indicator that you see, as a user with between [2k](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) and 10k reputation, is the number of pending **suggested edits**. It doesn't indicate anything about other kinds of reviews. There is an indicator for suggested edits because they are more urgent than other kinds of reviews. Sure, it's best to get working on advice to new users, close votes, etc. quickly, but the world doesn't stop while they're being reviewed. Pending suggested edits *do* stop the world, or at least a corner of it — while there is a pending suggested edit on a post, others can't suggest another edit.

Starting at 500 reputation, you can [access some review queues](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), but there's no indicator to nag you until you have more experience on the site.

Users with more than [10k reputation](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) see a different indicator, which is the total number of pending reviews. This indicator is not personalized (it includes posts that you've already reviewed or otherwise can't review) because the load on the server would be too much.